# Make one image out of two in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Frame:

[image: frame]

Avatar:
[image: avatar]

Need to make:

[image: result]

only transperent

```
from PIL import Image

background = Image.open("avatar.png")
foreground = Image.open("border.png")

foreground = foreground.resize((512, 512))

image = Image.new("RGBA", (512, 512))
image.paste(foreground, (0, 0))

image.paste(background, (512, 512), background)
image.show()
```

It doesn't work when I paste the frame after pasting the avatar because it completely overlaps the avatar, making it invisible. I've tried many other methods and searched, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do it like this:

- open and resize your existing images
- create transparent background
- paste avatar first, with offset
- paste frame second

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Set common size for everything
size = (512,512)

# Load frame and avatar, resizing to 512x512
avatar = Image.open("avatar.png").resize((180,180))
frame  = Image.open('frame.png').resize(size)

# Make transparent background for final image
image = Image.new("RGBA", size)
image.putalpha(0)

# Paste avatar onto background with positioning offset
image.paste(avatar, (170,170), avatar)
image.save('DEBUG-avatar-pasted.png')

# Paste frame over avatar and background retaining transarency
image.paste(frame, (0,0), frame)

# Save result
image.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

Here it is with a yellow background so you can see it on top of StackOverflow's annoying background colour:

[image]

---

Now that I have had more coffee, I note that:

```
image = Image.new("RGBA", size, color='#0000')
```

is more concise than the following for creating a transparent background:

```
image = Image.new("RGBA", size)
image.putalpha(0)
```

Comment: My pleasure - good luck with your project. Come back and ask a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: Can I have your help there?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78068140/make-one-image-out-of-avatar-and-frame-in-python-with-pillow

Answer (score 0):

image "border.png" don't have alpha channel.

delete white color to transparent.

or  Change the sequence

```
from PIL import Image

background = Image.open("avatar.png")
foreground = Image.open("border.png")

foreground = foreground.resize((512, 512))

image = Image.new("RGBA", (512, 512))

image.paste(background, (512, 512), background)
image.paste(foreground, (0, 0))
image.show()
```

Comment: It have, actually. Problem with upload.
https://imgur.com/a/Wy4Y898

Change of sequence doesn't help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).