# Make one image out of avatar and frame in Python with Pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

If I have

[image]

and

[image]

need to get

[image]

```
def create_avatar(username):
    avatar, frame, avatar_id = get_avatar(username)
    if avatar is not None and frame is not None:
        try:
            image = Image.new("RGBA", size)
            image.putalpha(0)

            # Paste avatar onto background with positioning offset
            image.paste(avatar, (157, 160), avatar)
            # image.save('DEBUG-avatar-pasted.png')

            # Paste frame over avatar and background retaining transarency
            image.paste(frame, (0, 0), frame)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            image = Image.open("images/unknown_avatar.png").resize((512, 512))
    elif avatar is not None:
        image = Image.open(f"images/{avatar_id}.png").resize((512, 512))
    else:
        image = Image.open("images/unknown_avatar.png").resize((512, 512))

    image.save(f'images/{username}.png', format='png')
```

I have a problem with Bad transperancy mask, but need to do that

Output image sizes needs to be 512x512

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. The problem is that the frame needs to be converted to "RGBA" first.

Consider that the avatar does not need a mask or an alpha channel. You are just pasting a solid image on the canvas image. It's the frame that needs attention in these regards.

```py
from PIL import Image

frame  = Image.open(f"front.png").convert('RGBA')
avatar = Image.open(f"back.jpg")

image  = Image.new("RGBA", frame.size, "#00000000")

image.paste(avatar, (85, 85))
image.paste(frame, (0, 0), frame)

image.resize((512,512)).save('result.png', format='png')
```

[image]